# Best way of sending users location from an android device to a c# server

Tags: c#, android, notifications, gps, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there another way of sending the users location than hitting my c# server every 30 sec with updated locations? I was thinking more in lines with a realtime solution while still having the MVC server as the backend, which is going to update a central screen.

It must be said that its only for 10 mins once a day the application are using the gps and network so intensively.

Anybody with some great ideas?

Also i need to send it realtime to a webpage, or the realtime tracking wont be attractive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only send the location if it has changed since the last time you sent it.

Comment: Its changing all the time at that moment, but only for 10 mins as is in the post.

Comment: No, it's not.  Unless the person is walking or in a moving vehicle.

Comment: All are moving in a vehicles.

Comment: I was hearing about signalR I dont know if it would help me

Comment: 5 to 10 mins once or maybe twice every day.

Comment: No, you didn't understand the question.  Within that 5 to 10 minute period, how often does the location need to be updated?  Your original question seems like it is "How can I get updates at 30 second intervals without sending data at 30 second intervals," and the answer to that question is "You can't."

Comment: ah okay, realtime would be the best, but as often as possible. I would like to get the time down.

Comment: What do you consider real-time?  Every 10 seconds?  Once per minute?

Comment: every 1-5 seconds would be realtime but 10 seconds would also be effecient

Comment: Then you have to send an update every 10 seconds.  You knew I was going to say that, right?

Comment: But wouldnt it be better on the onLocationChange() to send it there, and i was just thinking in performance and battery life if it sends every 10 second with many users, then maybe an acync method or framework could maybe help..

Comment: Yes, that's what my answer says (only send the location if it has changed since the last time you sent it).  But if the phone is constantly moving, it may give you a location change every 10 seconds, whether you use `onLocationChange()` or not.

Comment: Ill test it out and get back to you in a day

Comment: It seems to be okay with sending coordinates every 5 sec, onChange that is.